# Date Picker And Table View

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I'm working on a project on iPhone and I want a Date Picker on a few of the rows in the table view.

Please help me out.

Comment: learn from here http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/add-datepicker-programmatically-and-display-date-in-iphone/

Comment: i think in your application, you want to modify the date which shows in the particular row of table view. am i right? if no,then briefly explain what's your task?then i can give some suggestion.

Comment: i have a table View and on certain rows of mine i want to set Date Picker and add a label to the corresponding row showing the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a StaticCell TablieView, then you can just add these via storyboard.

If not, you will need to use the cellForRowAtIndexPath to determine which cell you want to add the datepicker to.  You would then instantiate a UIDatePicker, set the attributes if needed and add that subview to your cell.

One warning - using something this large in an iPhone TableView app will result in a crappy user experience.